# System.Drawing.BitmapSuffixInSameAssemblyAttribute missing in mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

I have a .NET MVC 5 application that I've been developing in Windows for some time. I'd like my Web Designer, who uses a Mac, to be able to run and edit the app locally on his Mac.

Short of building a Windows VM, Mono + Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio seems to be the best way to accomplish this.

When we first built the project, we got [an error about the System.Web.Entity.dll reference not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326382/). [We fixed that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34750186/1524502).

Now, though, we're getting an error that something is missing from the System.Drawing namespace.

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Drawing.BitmapSuffixInSameAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs:GetCustomAttributesInternal (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, Boolean inheritedOnly) [0x00019] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:128 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, Boolean inherit) [0x00017] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:290 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes (Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:244 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute (System.String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, System.Boolean& conflict) [0x0002c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration (System.String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation (System.String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) [0x0001e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load (System.String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup () [0x00021] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint () [0x0000d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T] (System.Threading.T& target, System.Boolean& initialized, System.Object& syncLock, System.Func`1 valueFactory) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/LazyInitializer.cs:241 
  at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T] (System.Threading.T& target, System.Boolean& initialized, System.Object& syncLock, System.Func`1 valueFactory) [0x00012] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/LazyInitializer.cs:206 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init (System.Web.HttpApplication context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CreateDynamicModules () [0x00030] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1676 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x000ad] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:218
```

I tried dropping the System.Drawing.dll file (and its associated .xml file) from my Windows box into the /bin folder, re-opening the project in Xamarin Studio, and the error changed to

```
Application Exception
System.InvalidProgramException
Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.BitmapSuffixInSatelliteAssemblyAttribute:.ctor (): method body is empty.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs:GetCustomAttributesInternal (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, Boolean inheritedOnly) [0x00019] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:128 
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (ICustomAttributeProvider obj, Boolean inherit) [0x00017] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:290 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCustomAttributes (Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:244 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute (System.String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, System.Boolean& conflict) [0x0002c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration (System.String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation (System.String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) [0x0001e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load (System.String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup () [0x00021] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint () [0x0000d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T] (System.Threading.T& target, System.Boolean& initialized, System.Object& syncLock, System.Func`1 valueFactory) [0x00037] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/LazyInitializer.cs:241 
  at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T] (System.Threading.T& target, System.Boolean& initialized, System.Object& syncLock, System.Func`1 valueFactory) [0x00012] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/LazyInitializer.cs:206 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init (System.Web.HttpApplication context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CreateDynamicModules () [0x00030] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1676 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x000ad] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:218 
Version Information: 4.2.1 (explicit/6dd2d0d Fri Nov 6 12:25:19 EST 2015); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
```

How can my designer run this .NET MVC 5 app natively on his Mac?

Comment: why do you need to use System.Drawing? can you drop the reference to this library in your original project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Whatever is referencing System.Drawing is way, way deep inside the .NET MVC framework. I'm not explicitly calling it in my app, nor did I have a reference originally. So, yes, I assume that I need it. If I'm reading the stack trace right, it's mono that's ultimately making the call.

Comment: The call is probably buried in the Owin middleware, actually. It's hard to tell from the Exception where the call/requirement for System.Drawing is being made.

Comment: ok, hang in there, I have a fix almost ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented stubs for the missing types in Mono's BCL, and proposed [a pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/2434).

As it has already been accepted and merged, this problem should be fixed in v.NEXT version of Mono (most likely named 4.4).

Comment: Hooray for open source!