# The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

Error :=- **AuthorizationServer.Api/Startup.cs(17,17): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (AuthorizationServer.Api)**

i am using visual studio community for mac and first error was system.web.http error so i follow the approach listed here:-

> [MVC 5 on Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Entity' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326382/mvc-5-on-mono-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-entity-or-one-of-its)

Installed System.Web.Common.Http But Following Error It is Showing In my startup.cs File How to resolve This ?
[image]

code:-

```
using AuthorizationServer.Api.Formats;
using AuthorizationServer.Api.Providers;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Common;

namespace AuthorizationServer.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration config = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();

            // Web API routes
            config.HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }
```

Comment: Have you added it as a reference?

Comment: Yes @SimonPrice

Answer (score 3):

after referencing the following NuGet: *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Core Libraries*

[image]

these are my Owin packages i have referenced:

[image]

**startup.cs** looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Removed for clarity
        // ConfigureOAuth(app);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: JWTAspNetWebApi-master/AuthorizationServer.Api/Startup.cs(20,20): Error CS1061: 'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (AuthorizationServer.Api)                      After adding its showing this error @Daniel

Comment: try: HttpConfigurationExtensions.MapHttpAttributeRoutes

Comment: Error CS1061: 'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'HttpConfigurationExtensions' and no extension method 'HttpConfigurationExtensions' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (AuthorizationServer.Api) . this error

Comment: same error as above coming .Error CS1061: 'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (AuthorizationServer.Api)

Comment: can you add all your namespaces that you are using ?

Comment: sorry @Amey. as i wrote it works on my machine (of course that doesn't help) may you try removing all of your usings.

Comment: @Amey i have added my Owin References. May this helps. Added my startup.cs class. This has to be working!

Comment: Having Same packages installed still same error on which os you Working  ?

Answer (score 0):

HttpConfiguration represents a configuration of HttpServer instances.

It is in the

> System.Web.Http library

Comment: i told that system.web.http error was rthere to resolve it i followed the above post as this lib is not available on mac