# Visual Studio for Mac not able to open previous projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have projects that I have made in the past in Microsoft Visual Studio. Recently, I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac and tried opening up these solutions but I am met with an error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Entity". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. (MSB3245) (WebApplication1)

Has anyone else ran into this? I am trying to Google this and see if there is anything remotely close but to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326382/mvc-5-on-mono-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-entity-or-one-of-its

Comment: ASP.NET 4.x is not something officially supported like ASP.NET Core on macOS. If you want to use ASP.NET 4.x, stick to Windows. If you want to use macOS and VS for Mac, use ASP.NET Core. There is almost no gray area in between to discuss.

Comment: @LexLi ahhh I understand. What about installing Parallels on my Mac and then Visual Studio on that to open up these files? Beginning to think owning a Windows computer is probably the way to go!