# building .NET fail: Could not load the file 'System.Web.Entity'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nuget

I am very beginner in .NET, need to run an web app, and it raise this error. I am using Visual Studio for Mac.

All I did add some 'Web.Entity' framework in NuGet package manager. Anyway I am totally lost.

[image]

[image]

---

I did also add DLL to the project, but it was one step forward, but still conculded to an other issue:

I followed hints here:

[MVC 5 on Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Entity' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326382/mvc-5-on-mono-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-entity-or-one-of-its)

[image]

Comment: Whatever `System.Web.Entity` is, it has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It's not needed for creating ASP.NET Core projects on Mac - I'm doing that right now, building various reporting projects using ASP.NET Core MVC, Razor Pages and even Blazor

Comment: Are you trying to build an ASP.NET Old MVC project on Mac? That's [not supported by Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/), only WebForms was. Mono's (and Xamarin's) aim was to create build *desktop* applications for Mac using .NET. With ASP.NET Core there's just no reason to use Mono for cross-platform web apps